# I can't `make` OpenCV 3.1 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: qt, c++, make, opencv

I'm trying to `make` OpenCV 3.1 after I generate the build with cmake-gui.
I get this error

```
[ 16%] Generating precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:59:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62,
             from /home/demgall/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:53,
             from /home/demgall/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
             from /home/demgall/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:52,
             from /home/demgall/Documents/OpenCV/release/modules/core/precomp.hpp:49:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1402: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know what other information I can handle. Just ask me what you need and I'll give it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully dug into what's actually happening but basically gcc can't find some of the system header files when building the PCH related code.

The PCH support CMake file (`cmake/OpenCVPCHSupport.cmake`) uses gcc's `-isystem` flag to set the directories where header files will be looked for and it looks like the compiler is getting a bit confused with that...

A simple solution that I found was to replace the `-isystem` with `-I`. You can make this change with the following command:

```
sed -i '/_PCH_isystem_prefix/ s/"-isystem"/"-I"/' cmake/OpenCVPCHSupport.cmake
```

That solves the issue on version 3.1.0, using gcc 6.5.0

See the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) for more info about the difference between these and other similar flags.

Comment: Just see this after a long hols break :) comment updated.